# Laravel 4 displays php tags (@extends) on web page as a string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I've just started my first project using WAMP, however, the special php tags, (@section, @extends, @stop), and all the other tags are displayed as a string.

I've switched Laravel's error variable to true and it still comes up as a string.  I've checked Laravel's welcome.blade in my browser and although the html and css are working fine it displays the @ tags.  I've also tested the server by including  and that works fine.  I've checked everywhere online and there's no answers to this problem.

Here's an example:

```
@extends('layout')
 
@section('content')
    Users!
@stop
```

This displays:

```
@extends('layout') @section('content') Users!
```

Any help please?

Comment: @extends('layout')

@section('content') [code] @stop

Comment: Any specific reason you start with a 10 year old framework and not the latest version?

Comment: Most likely your view file doesn't have a `.blade.php` extension and thus doesn't get parsed by Blade

Comment: what @brombeer said sounds exactly like your problem. You need to add .blade.php to your file extension so your file would be called `layout.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you have blade file in a folder you need to add a folder name in extends

`@extends('folder_name.layout')`